# Node.JS / Grunt-Nodemon: ReferenceError: mode is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm currently learning Node.JS and want to improve my development speed with Grunt. I've installed the "grunt-cli" globally and also "grunt-nodemon" as a development resource locally through NPM. The goal is that Node.JS restarts, whenever a JavaScript file changed.

Here's what I get in the Console:

```
D:\Projects\NodeJS\Web\Board\>grunt
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: mode is not defined
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Here's my gruntfile.js:

```
//gruntfile.js
mode.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        nodemon: {
            all: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    watchedExtensions: ['js']
                }
            }
        },      
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon']);
};
```

The console is pointing at the same directory where as the gruntfile.js is.

If you have any idea, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: try removing the comma  on the fourth last-line, after the bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 1 of your code is

```
mode.exports
```

it should be

```
module.exports   // change mode to module. Its a typo in your code
```

Hence the error

```
ReferenceError: mode is not defined
```

check the typo. Happy coding.

Comment: Went through this like 10 times. hahaha

Thank you very much!

Comment: Happens sometimes. Happy Coding mate!